# Change username for BitBucket from Android Studio without Terminal

Tags: android, android-studio, bitbucket

I tried changing BitBucket username through Terminal but want to change it through Android Studio. Is there an option available in VCS or Version control so as to change it?

Here is my example:

[image]

I want to change username "Laxmi" to "Nikhil".

Answer (score 5):

First off, check your git configuration if the email address set on your git config file matches the email address set on your Bitbucket user profile

$ git config -l

Resolution

If your email address set on your git configuration file does not match the email address set on your Bitbucket Server user profile, this is expected behavior and you need to configure your local Git client accordingly. If you want to see a different user on that column you must update your Git configuration and perform a new commit:

$ git config --global user.name "John Doe"

$ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com

check this url

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/commit-in-bitbucket-server-shows-a-different-username-than-the-one-that-pushes-the-code-779171816.html

Comment: Perfect solution, thank you so much! Saved much of my time!